# use socket and return with fake ip

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to use socket lib to show ip and I'm wondering if I can return it with fake ip

Code like this :

in start.py there is :

```
import socket
realip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
print realip
```

Then I made socket.py beside start.py and the start.py takes information of socket lib from new file socket.py.

in socket.py I but this code :

```
def getfqdn(ip):
    return "1.1.1.1"

def gethostbyname(ip):
    return ip
```

But it's didn't work, How can I do this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you define that it needs an argument

```
def getfqdn(ip):
    return "1.1.1.1"
```

and you aren´t passing any argument after the **getfqdn()**

```
realip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
```

**Fixes:**

**1st-**
without the argument as it doesn´t need it

```
def getfqdn():
    return "1.1.1.1"
```

**2nd-**
Or just set ip to None so no value is required

```
def getfqdn(ip=None):
    return "1.1.1.1"
```